# Use Angular2 component in Angular4

Tags: angular, charts, npm

Is there any chance to use angular2 components in angular4?
In my case i want to use library to generate charts:
https://devarchy.com/angular/ng2-nvd3, but unfortunately its dependencies are too low for my app. Aren't angular2 components compatible with angular4?

NPM trying install of pck

```
QLOOK2@0.0.0 D:\QLook2\App\trunk\QLook2.Client
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.2.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.2.4
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ngrx/store@2.2.2
`-- ng2-nvd3@2.0.0-rc3
  +-- d3@3.5.17
  +-- nvd3@1.8.5
  `-- rxjs@5.2.0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ngrx/devtools@1.4.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngrx/devtools@1.4.0 requires a peer of @ngrx/store@^1.5.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-google-maps@0.17.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-google-maps@0.17.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-select2@1.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.2.0 but none was installed.
```

PS. I'm not able to downgrade apps' libraries
PS2. I need this lib because there are multi Y-axis which are necessary in my app.

Comment: Normaly, you can use a majority of Angular 2 component in Angular 4 :)

Comment: Install it, and you will see WARN errors like this for your new library. But it will work, it's just that the required versions for that library don't match the ones you have installed. If it doesn't work, install both versions of its dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found (it's not for long term):

Go to node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib and open the Server.js.

```
Server.prototype.checkHost = function(headers) {
    ...

    // disallow
    return false;
}
```

change the "return false" to "return true".
Save and run again your project.

Answer (score 0):

Components built in Angular 2 can be used in Angular 4 but the modules which are used in angular 2 version are only compatible with that version.So the answer your query you have to install the module which is compatible with angular 4 version.